# How to get bitcoin balance in smart contract

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, bitcoin

I am making a smart contract and want to know the bitcoin balance of a metamask address.How can I do this? Since BTC is not ERC-20.

Comment: Metamask is an ethereum blockchain wallet and cannot hold bitcoin directly.
A workaround called WBTC (wrapped-bitcoin) exists. This is an ERC-20 token which claims to be fully backed by BTC.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a block explorer (something like [blockstream.info](https://blockstream.info))

All you need to know is the address you want to query.

I assume want to do automate this, and in this case you can search for an api -  http://blockchain.info/api
You will have to implement the API, but that's the only way as far as I know from a smart contract running on Etherium.

Comment: I see. I wanted to do something without an API.